# Java Ebean ORM - отношение ManyToMany

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

Собственно, вот мои модели с отношением ManyToMany:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "public")
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", schema = "public",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName   = "id"))
    public Collection<Role> roles;

    // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "roles", schema = "public")
public class Role extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    public Collection<User> users;

    public Role() { }

    public Role(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Сам запрос из действия, где `id` - идентификатор юзера:

```
User user = User.db().find(User.class).fetch("roles").where().eq("id", id).findUnique();
```

При попытке выполнить этот запрос получаю такую ошибку:

```
CompletionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting BeanDescriptor for path roles from models.User
```

И еще один странный момент: когда я использую `List<T>` для полей, которые ссылаются на другую таблицу, то получаю такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]->models.Role["users"]->com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]
```

... и так далее. Т.е. `Collection<Role>` - все ок, `List<Role>` - ошибка выше.

В чем может быть проблема? Все делал по гайдам и понять никак не могу где ошибка.